# Logging and profiling - automatic logging through annotations

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, logging, aspect-oriented

I am working with a little project intended to allow applications to benefit from aspect oriented programming. The first aspect is logging, which is already working. However I want this code to be more performatic and cleaner.

[Whole project](https://github.com/FilipeGMiranda/Green-Aspect-Utils)

The basic goals is to annotate methods - private/public static or instance - with and Custom annotation [`@LoggableObjects`](https://github.com/FilipeGMiranda/Green-Aspect-Utils/blob/master/src/main/java/org/greentea/aspect/log/annotation/LoggableObject.java). This annotation has options to define level of log - how much information to log (only args values, profiling information).

Since it uses reflection in many steps, I am afraid I might have missed something. I would appreciate if anyone reviewed my code.

This code processes the annotations and instruments the methods. How can the method `aroundObjects` be better executed? Is this a valid idea?

```
package org.greentea.aspect.log;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.Signature;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.greentea.aspect.log.annotation.LoggableObject;

/**
 * LoggableObjects are either Methods or Constructors that migh be logged <br>
 * The information logged is the method signature, its arguments and execution
 * time
 * 
 * The level of verbosity, and information might be configurable through the use
 * of the annotation @LoggableObjet
 * 
 * @author Filipe Gonzaga Miranda
 */
@Aspect
public class LoggableObjects {

    PluggableLogger pluggableLogger;

    public static ConcurrentMap<Class<? extends PluggableLogger>, PluggableLogger> cachedLoggers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    static{
        cachedLoggers.putIfAbsent(DefaultPluggableLoggerIfNotInjected.class, new DefaultPluggableLoggerIfNotInjected());
    }

    /**
     * Captures the Annotations {@link LoggableObjects}
     * 
     * And applies the logic to decide how to log the information based on the
     * LogModes
     * 
     * @param proJoinPoint
     * @return
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(LoggableObject)")
    public Object aroundObjects(ProceedingJoinPoint proJoinPoint)
            throws Throwable {
        Signature methodSignature = proJoinPoint.getSignature();
        String declaringClass = methodSignature.getDeclaringTypeName();
        String methodName = methodSignature.getName();
        Object[] args = proJoinPoint.getArgs();

        LoggableObject loggObject = getLoggableObjectAnnt(args, methodSignature);

        if (loggObject.disable()) {
            return proJoinPoint.proceed();
        }

        Class<? extends PluggableLogger> clazzPluggLogg = loggObject.pluggableLoggerClass();

        if(clazzPluggLogg != DefaultPluggableLoggerIfNotInjected.class){
            if(cachedLoggers.containsKey(clazzPluggLogg)){
                pluggableLogger = cachedLoggers.get(clazzPluggLogg);
            }else{
                pluggableLogger = clazzPluggLogg.newInstance();
                cachedLoggers.putIfAbsent(clazzPluggLogg, pluggableLogger);
            }
        }else{
            pluggableLogger = cachedLoggers.get(clazzPluggLogg);
        }

        LoggableObject.LogModes[] logModes = loggObject.logMode();

        boolean profileMode = false;
        boolean argsMode = false;
        boolean methodMode = false;

        logModesLoop: for (int i = 0; i < logModes.length; i++) {
            switch (logModes[i]) {
            case ALL:
                profileMode = true;
                argsMode = true;
                methodMode = true;
                break logModesLoop;
            case PROFILE:
                profileMode = true;
                break;
            case METHOD_NAME:
                methodMode = true;
                break;
            case ARGS:
                argsMode = true;
                break;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError("Operation not supported. "
                        + logModes[i].name());
            }
        }

        PluggableLogger logger = pluggableLogger;

        // getting modifiers
        if (methodMode || argsMode) {
            logger.logInfo(String.format(
                    "Entering execution of method %s, of class %s", methodName,
                    declaringClass));
        }


        if (argsMode && args.length > 0) {
            logger.logInfo(String.format("Arguments of method %s are: %s",
                    methodName, java.util.Arrays.toString(args)));
        }

        Object returnObject;
        try {
            long startNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
            returnObject = proJoinPoint.proceed();
            long execTime = System.nanoTime() - startNanoTime;
            if (profileMode) {
                logger.logInfo(String.format(
                        "Finished execution of %s in %s nanoTime", methodName,
                        execTime));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.logError("\nException in the method " + methodName
                    + " of class: " + methodSignature.getDeclaringTypeName());
            if (!loggObject.exceptionOnlyToExceptions()) {
                throw e;
            }
            logger.logWarning("Exception " + e + " supressed. Setting returning value to null...");

            returnObject = null;
        }
        return returnObject;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private LoggableObject getLoggableObjectAnnt(Object[] args, Signature methodSignature) throws Exception{
        int loadedClasses = 0;
        Class<?> clazzTypes[] = new Class[args.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            Class<?> clazz = null;
            if (args[i] == null) {
                String completeSignature = methodSignature.toLongString();

                Pattern p = Pattern
                        .compile("[\\w+.-]+([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\\d_$]*\\.)*[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\\d_$]*");

                Matcher m = p.matcher(completeSignature);

                m.find();
                m.find();
                m.find();
                int pos = 0;
                while(pos < loadedClasses){
                    m.find();
                    pos++;
                }
                m.find();
                String clazzName = m.group();
                clazz = Class.forName(clazzName);
                loadedClasses++;
            }else{
                clazz = args[i].getClass();
                loadedClasses++;
            }
            clazzTypes[i] = clazz;
        }


        return methodSignature.getDeclaringType()
                .getDeclaredMethod(methodSignature.getName(), clazzTypes)
                .getAnnotation(LoggableObject.class);

    }

    /**
     * Default implementation of {@link PluggableLogger} using
     * {@link java.util.logging.Logger} internally to Log msgs
     * @author Filipe Gonzaga Miranda
     */
    public static class DefaultPluggableLoggerIfNotInjected implements PluggableLogger{

        @Override
        public void logInfo(String msg) {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("greentea.logger");
            logger.log(Level.INFO, msg);
        }

        @Override
        public void logError(String msg) {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("greentea.logger");
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, msg);
        }

        @Override
        public void logWarning(String msg) {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("greentea.logger");            
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, msg);
        }

        @Override
        public PluggableLogger getForCache() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "DefaultPluggableLoggerIfNotInjected - It has a java.util.logging.Logger";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know little about AspectJ, but have a number of more basic points to call out in your code.

### Hygiene

- `cachedLoggers` should be `private static final` and not `public static`. Do you really want anyone to be able to replace your instance?
- `PluggableLogger pluggableLogger` is an instance field, but it should be in the method only (perhaps just called `logger`). As things are at the moment, you risk a race condition when the method is called concurrently.... you could be overwriting the logger part-way through one call, with another call.
- `throws Throwable` .... really? you should always narrow your exceptions down more than that.
- `throw new AssertionError(...)` ... really? Why not just an `IllegalArgumentException`?

### Performance

- The `Pattern.compile(...)` should be a private-static-final field. The patterns are thread-safe, and designed to be reused.
- Instead of a ConcurrentMap I would consider a thread-local HashMap. This would require benchmarking to resolve, but, it could be significantly better at memory management, especially when there's only the default plugin used.
- You can do the `isDisabled` check before getting the declaring class, and method name
- You jump through hoops getting the `clazzPluggLogg` ..:

  > ```
  > Class<? extends PluggableLogger> clazzPluggLogg = loggObject.pluggableLoggerClass();
  >
  > if(clazzPluggLogg != DefaultPluggableLoggerIfNotInjected.class){
  >     if(cachedLoggers.containsKey(clazzPluggLogg)){
  >         pluggableLogger = cachedLoggers.get(clazzPluggLogg);
  >     }else{
  >         pluggableLogger = clazzPluggLogg.newInstance();
  >         cachedLoggers.putIfAbsent(clazzPluggLogg, pluggableLogger);
  >     }
  > }else{
  >     pluggableLogger = cachedLoggers.get(clazzPluggLogg);
  > }
  > ```

  this can be done instead as:

  ```
  Class<? extends PluggableLogger> clazzPluggLogg = loggObject.pluggableLoggerClass();
  pluggableLogger = cachedLoggers.computeIfAbsent(clazzPluggLogg, k -> k.newInstance());
  ```

  The above will lock the map only once, not multiple times.

Comment: Excellent Review, I will be applying this to my project, about the AssertionError, I read this idiom in "Effective Java", I thought it was the better, but you say it is simplier to use IllegalArgumentException, I think you re right, because, it is a more well known exception. Again, thanks!